# Is it safe to use an Y2 Capacitor where an X capacitor used to be?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, line, metal-film

Is it safe to use an Y2 Capacitor where an X capacitor used to be?
I mean Y should be safer right? So Y2 where X should be is OK, but not the other way around, right?

Comment: More details, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Y rated caps are also approved for use as X rated caps. Look at the marking on the cap, you should find something like X1Y2, or X1/Y2, which means that it has been approved for use as either a X1 rated or Y2 rated cap.

Comment: It is one of these:http://www.digikey.se/product-search/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/131088?k=PME271Y&pv13=40&pv1292=25&FV=fff40002%2Cfff80010&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25
that is replacing a similar rated X-cap in an old sewing machine.

Comment: @JohnyTex that one doesn't show in it's datasheet as being X1 or X2 rated. However Digikey has [these 3](http://www.digikey.se/product-search/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/131088?k=&pv508=143&FV=fff40002%2Cfff80010%2C142798%2C142799%2C340028&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) which have the same capacitance which are X1 or X2 rated, so why not just use one of those?

Comment: I already bought it and mounted actually. Do you think I have something  to worry about?

Comment: So what can happen electrically? I won't hold anyone accountable. ;-)

Comment: @JohnyTex Since this is just for a repair it will be OK.